# Create multiple methods in one action class itself in Struts2?

Tags: java, struts2, struts

Can I create two methods in the same Action Class? If so how can we specify it in the `struts.xml` file ?

For example : I created a simple validation action class to validate the `email address` as well as `password` using two separate regular expression.
I created two Methods in the Action class say: `emailVerification()` and `passVerification()`.
I wrote all the necessary validation code inside, but now when they return `SUCCESS` they should result into the same success page result and for `ERROR` likewise..

Comment: Yes, you can have more than one method in action class, obviously. What is the real issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can create any number of methods in an Action Class. You can do something like this

```
package com.myvalidation;

public class MyValidationClass extends ActionSupport
{
     public String emailVerification() throws Exception
     {
         //Your validation logic for email validation
         return SUCCESS;
     }

     public String passVerification() throws Exception
     {
         //Your validation logic for password validation
         return SUCCESS;
     }
}
```

`struts.xml`

```
<action name="emailVerification" method="emailVerification" class="com.myvalidation.MyValidationClass">
        <result name="success">/your_success_jsp.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/your_error_jsp.jsp</result>
</action> 

<action name="passVerification" method="passVerification" class="com.myvalidation.MyValidationClass">
    <result name="success">/your_success_jsp.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">/your_error_jsp.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Comment: doesnt this require two seperate form names ? so that it can be mapped to the action tag in struts.xml?

Comment: @sabby What do you mean by form names?

Comment: the name of the forms used in the View page i.e  <form name="validationpage" > ...... </form>  if i am not wrong these names are used to link them in the struts.xml where we user  <action name="validationpage" ...... >   correct me if i am wrong ..

Answer (score 1):

Using the folowing URL format you can call any public method from Struts action class:

> /ActionName!publicMethodName.action?p1=v1&p2=v2

For more information refer to: [Action Configuration](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/action-configuration.html)

Comment: This answer doesn't answers OP question.

Comment: With this approach there is no need in modifying struts.xml. I think it's easier than Uchenna's suggestion, which is also correct.

Comment: with Convention plugin you won't use struts.xml at all (except for global configs). And DMI is disabled by default in latest struts2 versions, because it's potentially harmful (read Dynamic Method Invocation in the link you posted).

Comment: Plus you are not showing how to create such url and configuration needed for it.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than code a separate mapping for each action class that uses this pattern, you can write it(method="{1}") once as a wildcard mapping.